# Discriminant mod 8

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Let $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be monic polynomials of degree $n$, with discriminants $\Delta_{f}$ and $\Delta_{g}$, such that $f=g$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$ and $\Delta_{f}$ is odd.

> Is there an elementary way to see that $\Delta_{f}\equiv\Delta_{g}$ mod 8?

(For even $\Delta_{f}$ this fails, as $f=X^{2}$ and $g=X^{2}+2X$ show.)

By a theorem of Stickelberger, if $r$ is the number of irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$, then $\Delta_{f}\equiv1$ mod 8 iff $n-r$ is even, and $\Delta_{f}\equiv5$ mod 8 otherwise. But this is a non-trivial result in algebraic number theory...